# Html.ActionLink doesn't accept HTML attributes

Tags: html, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to set the color of the hyperlink returned by `Html.ActionLink` in a Razor page. I want it to be red.

I tried setting HTML attributes when calling `ActionLink`:

```
Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { style = "color: red;" })
```

But it didn't give a visible effect.

**The strange thing is that only `ActionLink` behaves badly. I tried calling the `Label` method, and the label was red, as I set in the HTML attributes.**

If I use the `a` tag instead of that method, everything will work properly. But using method is more convenient for me. I hope it will again be a stupid error and I will be able to use `ActionLink` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { style = "color: red;"
> })

the signature like below:

```
public static string ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
                                string linkText,
                                string actionName,
                                string controllerName,
                                object values, 
                                object htmlAttributes)
```

[image]

You may miss the `routeValues` , try to do like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home",null,new { style="color: red;"})
```

result:

[image]